# counting occurence of a word in a text file using python

Tags: python, file, text-processing

I'm tring to count the occurence of a word in a text file.

```
sub = 'Date:'

#opening and reading the input file
#In path to input file use '\' as escape character
with open ("C:\\Users\\md_sarfaraz\\Desktop\\ctl_Files.txt", "r") as myfile:
    val=myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ')    


#val
#len(val)
occurence = str.count(sub, 0, len(val))
```

I'm getting this error :--

```
>>> occurence = str.count('Date:', 0,len(val))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
>>> occurence = str.count('Date:', 0,20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: @Wajdi's answer is the right approach. Also read about 'fileinput' module. It gives you similar functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `count` wrong. Try this:

```
occurence = val.count(sub)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks '@skyline75489'. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating it:

```py
open(file).read().count(WORD)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many times the word `Date:` occurs in the text file, this is one way to do it:

```
myfile = open("C:\\Users\\md_sarfaraz\\Desktop\\ctl_Files.txt", "r").read()
sub = "Date:"
occurence = myfile.count(sub)
print occurence
```